# .WRITE clause performance optimization

Tags: sql-server-2012, update, varchar

I have found that you can do `high performance updates` on `varchar(max),nvarchar(max),varbinary(max)` columns using the `.WRITE` clause([example here](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2011/10/04/update-statement-with-new-write-clause/) and [here](http://sqlsolace.blogspot.com/2013/01/update-write-sql-2012.html)). Unfortunately, there is nothing mentioned about performance optimization in the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx).

Could anyone tell is there any optimization at all? Has anyone made some performance test? Also if there is optimization I guess it will affect only specific situations, too.

Comment: One potential performance improvement would be that partial updates with `.WRITE` are only minimally logged.  If you are updating a large amount of rows, this would result in lower IO to the log file, possibly leading to higher performance.

Comment: Also, `.WRITE` does not need to rewrite the contents of the column, it simply modifies the data already in the column.  This indicates less IO is necessary on the table itself.

Comment: There is a significant performance difference if your lob column store more than 8000 bytes. For in-row data there is little if any difference. When you test you could use `set statistics io on` and have a look at the difference in lob logical reads.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Thanks for the suggestions - very interesting - I am not observing any `lob read-ahead reads` at all.

Comment: @MaxVernon Could you give official source confirming this? This clause seems to be very powerful, I cannot understand why there is no more information about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WRITE` method is minimally logged. If you use regular `UPDATE` statement, it would result in overwriting the entire string using `FULL LOGGING`. This would become inefficient when dealing with large updates.

To support update for large value data types, the `UPDATE` syntax supports `.WRITE` method. This will result in less Transaction log due to its nature of minimal logging - **including insert or appending new data**.

Note : The `UPDATE` using `WRITE` method will fail if the target `LOB` is `NULL`.

Below is a quick and dirty repro showing the transaction log generated using `REGULAR UPDATE` and `UPDATE` using `.WRITE` method.

```
--- create table

create table dbo.testWRITEUpdate (
    ID int identity(1, 1)
    ,COMMENTS varchar(MAX) not null
    )
go

insert into dbo.testWRITEUpdate (COMMENTS)
values (REPLICATE(CAST('KIN' as varchar(max)), 9000))

checkpoint
go
```

--- Regular Update:

```
set statistics io on
 begin tran
update dbo.testWRITEUpdate
set COMMENTS =  STUFF(COMMENTS, 9, 55, '$$$$$(((())))))))))))))____GarbageData____ Entered ____')
where ID  =1

set statistics io off
go

commit tran
```

-- stats IO output

```
 Table 'testWRITEUpdate'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 15, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 6.
```

-- Transaction Log Generated --> **6 Log records with 54580 bytes**:

[image]

Update using `WRITE` method :

```
begin tran
set statistics io on
update dbo.testWRITEUpdate
set COMMENTS.WRITE('$$$$$(((())))))))))))))____GarbageData____ Entered ____',9,55)
where ID  =1
set statistics io off

commit tran
go
```

-- Stats IO

```
Table 'testWRITEUpdate'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 1, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

-- Transaction Log Generated --> **3 log records with 464 bytes**:

[image]

The above test proves that the `WRITE` method provides more benefit in terms of Transaction log generated as it is minimally logged operation + incurring less logical reads.

*Note*: This is just scratching the surface, there can be more tests done to *actually* prove in terms of performance if WRITE method is performing better than the regular UPDATE especially when dealing with VARCHAR, NVARCHAR OR VARBINARY datatypes.

---

Update (As requested by OP):

Below is the query for finding the `sys.dm_tran_database_transactions`

```
SELECT [database_transaction_log_bytes_used] FROM sys.dm_tran_database_transactions
WHERE [database_id] = DB_ID ('test_kin');
GO
```

--- or a more detailed version :

```
SELECT DTST.[session_id], 
 DES.[login_name] AS [Login Name], 
 DB_NAME (DTDT.database_id) AS [Database], 
 DTDT.[database_transaction_begin_time] AS [Begin Time], 
 -- DATEDIFF(ms,DTDT.[database_transaction_begin_time], GETDATE()) AS [Duration ms], 
 CASE DTAT.transaction_type 
   WHEN 1 THEN 'Read/write' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Read-only' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'System' 
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Distributed' 
  END AS [Transaction Type], 
  CASE DTAT.transaction_state 
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Not fully initialized' 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Initialized, not started' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Active' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Ended' 
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Commit initiated' 
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Prepared, awaiting resolution' 
    WHEN 6 THEN 'Committed' 
    WHEN 7 THEN 'Rolling back' 
    WHEN 8 THEN 'Rolled back' 
  END AS [Transaction State], 
 DTDT.[database_transaction_log_record_count] AS [Log Records], 
 DTDT.[database_transaction_log_bytes_used] AS [Log Bytes Used], 
 DTDT.[database_transaction_log_bytes_reserved] AS [Log Bytes RSVPd], 
 DEST.[text] AS [Last Transaction Text], 
 DEQP.[query_plan] AS [Last Query Plan] 
FROM sys.dm_tran_database_transactions DTDT 
 INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions DTST 
   ON DTST.[transaction_id] = DTDT.[transaction_id] 
 INNER JOIN sys.[dm_tran_active_transactions] DTAT 
   ON DTST.[transaction_id] = DTAT.[transaction_id] 
 INNER JOIN sys.[dm_exec_sessions] DES 
   ON DES.[session_id] = DTST.[session_id] 
 INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections DEC 
   ON DEC.[session_id] = DTST.[session_id] 
 LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests DER 
   ON DER.[session_id] = DTST.[session_id] 
 CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (DEC.[most_recent_sql_handle]) AS DEST 
 OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan (DER.[plan_handle]) AS DEQP 
ORDER BY DTDT.[database_transaction_log_bytes_used] DESC;
-- ORDER BY [Duration ms] DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks that's interesting. Also, you can point that `If the statement inserts or appends new data, the operation is minimally-logged if the database recovery model is simple or bulk-logged` and `Updates to existing data are not minimally-logged` - so I guess in `FULL` recovery model the logging is not a factor (http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/77/Posts/17835/0201-sql-server-update-statement-use-write-for-partial-updates.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I have also checked your code on `FULL` recovery model database and there is indeed less logging when `.WRITE` is used. I guess the link above is wrong.